# transmit signal with hackrf one

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I want to use hackrf one to transmit a continuous signal. my question is that "can hackrf transmit signal continuously or it has certain interrupt between its transmission?" my question is because of when I detect transmitted signal, It is  mismatch to its origin.

Comment: yes it can. There's countless blogs, papers and videos demonstrating that.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Somehow I don't think this was your signal processing question!